# Dmesg boot dumps, udev and boot time

Tags: boot, kernel, udev, dmesg

The following is my `dmesg` dump.

```
[    1.452016] udevd[121]: starting version 175
[    1.522976] thermal LNXTHERM:00: registered as thermal_zone0
[    1.522989] ACPI: Thermal Zone [THM] (76 C)
[    1.636230] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 2260.981 MHz
[    2.636606] Switched to clocksource tsc
[    4.628681] EXT4-fs (sda6): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[    4.628688] EXT4-fs (sda6): write access will be enabled during recovery
[    7.588994] EXT4-fs (sda6): recovery complete
[    7.610925] EXT4-fs (sda6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   20.633295] init: mounted-proc main process (307) terminated with status 1
[   20.712495] Adding 493564k swap on /dev/sda7.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:493564k FS
[   21.397395] udevd[372]: starting version 175
[   21.868082] loop: module loaded
[   23.077609] wmi: Mapper loaded
```

We can see that mounting `ext4` takes nearly 13 seconds.
Is it mounting that takes 13 seconds or the `udevd` that takes 13 seconds? 
`udevd` is initiated again around 21 second. Why is it that `udev` is started twice?

How do I optimize this feature? Any pointers on how I can approach this?

I run a custom `3.12.4` kernel, that I optimized for size, and my OS is Ubuntu 12.10
(Im attempting this for educational purposes only)

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu system, this is what I get:

```
  # dmesg | grep udevd
  [    0.616905] systemd-udevd[126]: starting version 204
  [    3.360394] systemd-udevd[418]: starting version 204
```

Same thing on my Debian, Arch systems. It seems to be quite standard (so no need to worry), even though I cannot explain why it happens either.